# Should I remove 'django.contrib.comments' from my installed apps when I modify it by subclassing?

Tags: django, django-comments

I'm customizing django comments.

According to the docs you'll need to add your customized app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py, and set COMMENTS_APP to your app name.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'my_comment_app',
    ...
]

COMMENTS_APP = 'my_comment_app'
```

Should I also remove 'django.contrib.comments' from INSTALLED_APPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only extending `contrib.comments` not replacing it, you shouldn't remove it from installed apps since, for example, most of the templatetags you need are in that application.

In order for Django to find the templates, templatetags and so on app must be in the installed apps.